# Incompatibility between SplashJsonResponse and Xpath()

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapy-splash

My problem is the following, my spider has just successfully clicked on a button within the function `parse_search_page()`. In the function `parse_identity` I am on the next page where I can start scraping some information. But the variable "response" is of type `SplashJsonResponse` which is not supported by `xpath()` and `response.body` is of type `bytes` which is as well not supported

The solutions of my problem that I think can work are:

- Convert `SplashJsonResponse` to `SplashTextResponse` (which is an html response)
- Use `xpath` on bytes
- Convert `scrapy_splash.response.SplashJsonResponse` to `scrapy.http.response.html.HtmlResponse`

Code:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.utils.response import open_in_browser
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quotes"
    start_urls = ['https://app.nominations.hospimedia.fr']

    def parse(self, response):
        # the function "callback" is called after you have logged in
        return scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
            response,
            formdata={'user[email]': 'XXX', 'user[password]': 'XXX'},
            callback=self.parse_landing_page
        )

    def parse_landing_page(self, response):
        # open webpage after logging in
        #open_in_browser(response)
        start_urls = 'https://app.nominations.hospimedia.fr'

        # we extract the title
        # title = response.xpath('//title/text()').extract()
        print("hello1")
        # regarder a quoi sert le extract() si on le mets pas
        next_page_partial_url = response.xpath('//div[@class="l-action l-action--small"]/a/@href').extract()
        #print(next_page_partial_url)
        next_page_url = start_urls + next_page_partial_url[0]

        yield scrapy.Request(next_page_url, callback=self.parse_search_page)

    def parse_search_page(self, response):
        # if you click on the page below you know if your scrapy-splash is working
        # http://localhost:8050/
        script = '''
            function main(splash, args)
            splash:go(splash.args.url)
            splash:runjs('document.getElementsByClassName("button tertiary")[0].click()')
            return {
                html = splash:html(),
            }
            end
        '''
        open_in_browser(response)
        print("----------")
        # scrapy.http.response.html.HtmlResponse
        print(type(response))
        print("------------")
        #yield SplashRequest(response.request.url, callback = self.parse_identity, endpoint='execute', args={'lua_source': script})
        yield SplashRequest(callback = self.parse_identity,
                             endpoint='execute',
                             args={'url':response.request.url,
                              'lua_source': script}
                             )

    def parse_identity(self, response):
        print("----------------------------------------")
        # scrapy_splash.response.SplashJsonResponse
        print(type(response))
        # <class 'bytes'>
        print(type(response.body))

        print(response.body)
        print(("----------------------------------------"))

        next_page_partial_url = response.xpath('//div[@class="medium-6 small-12 columns"]/text()').extract()

        #next_page_partial_url = response.xpath('//a[@rel="noopener noreferrer"]/text()').extract()
        print(next_page_partial_url)
        print(("----------------------------------------"))
        #inspect_response(response, self)
        #open_in_browser(response)
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually the solution is to use HtmlResponse

```
from scrapy.http import HtmlResponse

html_response = HtmlResponse(url=response.url, body=response.text, encoding='utf-8')
```